# make an image appear aligned (or floating) to the right

Tags: css, image, alignment, wordpress

I installed Wordpress User Photo plugin that allows to show an authors photo. So far so good, but I want it to be displayed not after the post date, but rather parrallel to the author's name and post date.
The following image explains it all :

[image]

it seems I managed to create a new CSS class.. I added in the css:

## featured-posts-block .user-photo {}

Then in the loop, I wrapped the user photo code in the same CSS thing, so it is now:

To test it, I added "border:2px solid blue;" to the CSS, and it showed up good..

But I am unable to make it float to the right of the text , like I demonstrated in the photo above. Help is appreciated.

It would be great if you please also tell me what how would the code look like if I want to resize the image when it is displayed.

The website where you can see it:
http://kuttabna.net

The code I am using to display that chunk:

```
<h2 class="entry-title"></a><a>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('رابط  %s', 'framework'), get_the_title()); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<!--BEGIN .entry-meta .entry-header-->
                        <div class="entry-meta entry-header">
                    <span class="published"> كتبها
                    <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>  </span>
                    <span class="meta-sep">·</span>
                    <span class="published"> في <?php the_time( get_option('date_format') ); ?>
<?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail() ?></span>
                            <!--END .entry-meta entry-header -->
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is being printed out inside of a div with class user-photo add a new Style to your page with the float: right for that class.. included margin-left 5px just for some spacing.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.user-photo{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Great, Thank you very much Brian!! Can you just please tell me how can I force different image size? I mean to resize it when it is displayed there ?
EDIT: Well I become a CSS expert lol , I added img at the end of the class (after I duplicated it) and added the width + height properties. Thank you again :)